# Adding a class to a specific field in a specific row inside repeater - Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

At the moment I used the long version to do this task but would like to use a repeater and just assign the 3rd row's text area a class of "normal".

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="content-details-right">
       <div class="content-deals">
           <div class="title-content">
               <h2><?php the_field('page_title') ?></h2>
           </div>

           <div class="title-info">
               <span><?php the_field('mission_title') ?></span>
               <em><?php the_field('mission_text_area') ?></em>
           </div>
           <div class="title-info">
               <span><?php the_field('vision_title') ?></span>
               <em><?php the_field('vision_text_area') ?></em>
           </div>
           <div class="title-info">
               <span> <?php the_field('objectives_title') ?></span>
               <em class="normal"><?php the_field('objectives_text_area') ?></em>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I would have a repeater with a title and a text area field. But only the last text area shouldnt be emphasised.

Comment: why cant you use jquery to add class?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class like this for last-child in jQuery

```
$('.content-deals .title-info:last-child em').addClass('normal');
```

if it is always 3rd row, then use this

```
$('.content-deals .title-info:nth-child(2) em').addClass('normal');
```